# Moment Js time format not working properly

Tags: momentjs

```
const dated = moment().format("MMMM DD YYYY HH:MM:SS");
```

is not giving correct time getting 22 minutes less than actual time and there is 20 seconds difference between original and seconds from above code

Answer (score 0):

### MM - MONTH | `mm - minutes` | SS - MILLISECONDS | `ss - seconds`

The difference between the original time and the time you are seeing is due to `case sensitivity`. Moment.js format() method accepts case-sensitive formats.

The minutes you might be seeing would be `9` since you are actually asking for a month ( `MM` ) which is `September (9)`

For getting the desired outcome modify your code as

```
const dated = moment().format("MMMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss");
```

[Check official moment.js documentation for more details](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

[Check my CodeSandbox work around here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/sof-6-x9m9m?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

The real issue was with the format specifiers. `MM` according to moment docs, stands for `Months`, Hence the difference. Also `SS` also indicates fractional seconds.

Check this snippet

```js
console.log(moment().format("MMMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

More options: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/